# Why does bloodhound.get() return undefined?

Tags: jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm trying to use the code below with typeahead.js v 0.10

```
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d; },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local:  ["(A)labama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas"]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();
console.log(numbers.get('a'));
```

In fact I try to solve this question: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/26
I expected something like shown below should be possible:

```
 $('.typeahead').typeahead(
{
items: 4,
source:function(query){return numbers.get(query)}       
});
```

**update**

The [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples). use `ttAdapter()` to set the source of typeahead. 
This function can also be used to set the `source` property (which accept an array of string or a function) for [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js):

```
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,//function(d) { return d; },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local:  ["(A)labama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","Arkansas2","Barkansas"]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(
{
items: 4,
source:numbers.ttAdapter()  
});
```

bloodhound.js shows:

```
  ttAdapter: function ttAdapter() {
                return _.bind(this.get, this);
            }
```

So `ttAdapter()` returns a function (get()) which can be set by source which has the query as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented Bloodhound.get() as follows (also see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/HS9Wy/):

```
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return d;
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: ["(A)labama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas"]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();

// Get an array of datums which satisfy the query for 'a'
numbers.get('a', function (suggestions) {
    jQuery.each(suggestions, function (index, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

The problem with your call to "get()" i.e.

```
numbers.get('a')
```

Is that whilst you are getting Bloodhound to execute the query for 'a' you are not doing anything with the results. To instruct "get()" to do something useful you need to send the results to the output function. See the [documentation here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#bloodhoundgetquery-cb).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in fact this still doesn't return anything?? I finally found from the examples http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples. `ttAdapter()` return a function which can be used to set the `source` of Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: Correct, "get()" doesn't return anything. Your question specifically asked why "get()" doesn't return anything, and I explained that you were using it incorrectly. Glad that you found ttAdapter after looking at the basic examples.