# Why are the typeahead suggestions undefined?

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js, bloodhound

Hopefully this is not a duplicate of: [Why does bloodhound.get() return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591086/why-does-bloodhound-get-return-undefined)

I upgraded to **typeahead.js version 0.10.0**. Prior versions were returning  the suggestions properly. Now I am getting an `undefined` return with the below code:

```
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return [d]; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: ["(A)labama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas"]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
engine.initialize();

$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucUcn/6/

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

The `local` array must contain objects, not strings themself.

```js
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('d'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: [{
    d: "(A)labama"
  }, {
    d: "Alaska"
  }, {
    d: "Arizona"
  }, {
    d: "Arkansas"
  }]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
engine.initialize();

$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'd',
  source: engine.ttAdapter()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<input id="typeahead" />
```

Fiddle with above fix:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMLL4/)

Comment: It works great when you type an `A` but if you type `Ar` it disappears

Comment: it looks like my link to typeahead is pointing to the latest version and there was breaking changes. Going to leave the updated version linked because in an ideal world you would be using the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chad said, the result array must contains objects.

I only wanted to add that the default value used to display the suggestion is `value`

So you could do something like

```
var suggestionEngine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: "myUrl",
        filter: function (suggestions) {
            var mappedResult = $.map(suggestions[1], function(suggestion) {
                return { value : suggestion }
            });

            return mappedResult;
        }
    }
});
```